# Helm template converting to json

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I would like to be able from Helm template file as below to insert template with **toJson** helm function as explained in the documentation :

```
value: {{ include "mytpl" . | lower | quote }}
```

https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#know-your-template-functions

**My configuration :**
_helper.tpl

```
{{- define "my_tpl" -}}
key1: value1
key2: value2
{{- end -}}
```

dep.yaml

```
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        test: >-
          {{ include "my_tpl" . | toJson }}
```

This should return

```
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        test: >-
          {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

but it return

```
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        test: >-
          "key1:value1\nkey2:value2"
```

I'm using Helm v3.
Anyone have an idea please ?

Answer (score 11):

A `define`d template *always* produces a string; the Helm-specific `include` function *always* returns a string.

In your example, you have a string that happens to be valid YAML.  Helm has an undocumented `fromYaml` function that converts the string to object form, and then you can serialize that again with `toJson`.

```
{{ include "my_tpl" . | fromYaml | toJson }}
```

You may find it easier to have the template itself produce the correct JSON serialization.  That could look something like

```
{{- define "my_tpl" -}}
{{- $dict := dict "key1" "value1" "key2" "value2" -}}
{{- toJson $dict -}}
{{- end -}}

{{ include "my_tpl" . }}
```

where the `"key1"`, `"value1"`, *etc.* can be any valid template expression (you do not need nested `{{ ... }}`).

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks you @David Maze ! I've choosen the first solution because my json is very long including hard regex so the first one is clearly the proper way for my case.